# Can I Attach Database in HTML5 WebSQL?

Tags: javascript, database, html

Can this scenario be done ?,

```
db = window.openDatabase('dataa', '1.0', 'Data B', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db2 = window.openDatabase('datab', '1.0', 'Data A', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

somehow attached like this ?

```
db.executeSql("attach 'datab' as b", [], success, failure);
```